# NN学習において､Valid Loss < Train Loss は悪ですか?

Tags: 機械学習

NN初心者です｡
ResNetのモデルで学習を行っているのですが､図の様にtrain loss >> valid lossとなってしまいます｡
これは問題でしょうか?
Dropoutの層があり､dropout率を低くするとtrain lossが改善するので､dropoutが無いvalidationで精度が高くなるということだと理解しています｡
目的はvalid lossを低くすることなので､train loss と valid lossの差は無視して､valid lossが最小となるようなチューニングをする､ということで良いのでしょうか｡
それとも､train lossとvalid lossがある程度近い状態を､汎化性能の高い状態として目指すべきでしょうか｡

初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが､御意見を頂けましたら有り難いです｡

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: trainデータとvalidデータ（の質）に大きな差があったりしませんか？

Comment: 有り難うございます｡確認したのですが､予測したい要素の分布には大きな差はありませんでした｡validationデータ選択のためのrandom_stateを固定しているのですが､それを変更しても同様にTrain loss >> Valid lossという結果でした｡

Comment: validationのlossの方が常に低いというのは経験がないので分かりませんが、グラフを見るとlossが高いようにも思います。画像認識モデルかと思われますが、精度についてはどれくらいなのでしょうか？

Comment: dropoutしないとどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: @merino Dropoutしないと､逆転して過学習になります｡精度は､連続値をターゲットにしているのですが､現時点ではあまり良くありません｡ただ､コードが間違っている可能性があるので､原因の解明をしているところです｡

Comment: 「Dropoutしないと､逆転して過学習になります｡」のときのlossは質問の画像よりも良いのでしょうか？データの質や枚数、dropout率など情報が少なく回答するのは難しそうですね。